# How do I sum up polygons in each squared grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, area, vector-grid

1. So I have created a square grid (fishnets) layers with another layer of Philippine mangrove distribution polygons, I intersected two layers so the Area1 (philipine mangrove polygons) and Area2 (square grids) and so their both area columns are in the same attribute table. However I want to calculate the percentage of mangrove polygons in each grid cells, I would need to sum the mangroves polygons for each grid cell.
   How can I do that? I know a way of doing it is via ArcMap's Tabulate Intersection function. Is there another function equivalent to qgis?
2. I also tried with join attribute by location from the data management tools, however the output layer's attribute table would just not contain the sum of Area1. Is it because that the mangrove polygons are not each wholly contained in grid cells but intersecting? What should I do then?

Comment: `I want to calculate the percentage of mangrove polygons in each grid cells` - so in your grid, you'd like an attribute that tells you how much (in %) that that grid is comprised of mangroves? Essentially getting to the point where you can calculate ("area of all mangroves in the grid" / "area of the grid") * 100?

Comment: Yes, exactly - (the sum of the area of all mangroves in a square cell of the fishnet grid/ the area of the square cell)*100

Answer (score 2):

A `Virtual Layer` approach:

- `mangrove` (layer name) your mangrove polygon
- `Grid` (layer name) your grid polygon

After importing these two layers, run this syntax.

```
SELECT Grid.ID AS GridID, 
       Round(Sum(st_area(st_intersection(Grid.geometry, mangrove.geometry))), 3) AS Mangrove_area, 
       Round(Sum(st_area(st_intersection(Grid.geometry, mangrove.geometry)))/st_area(Grid.geometry)*100, 3) AS Percentage
FROM Grid, mangrove
WHERE st_intersects(Grid.geometry, mangrove.geometry) 
GROUP BY Grid.ID
ORDER BY Grid.ID
```

Output (attribute table) of the `virtual layer` would be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, you could rasterize your polygon mangrove layer (assign pixels corresponding to mangrove polygons as 1 and everything else 0) and then use the `Raster` >`Zonal Statistics` algorithm to calculate both the "sum" and "count" statistics within each grid square. `Zonal Statistics` will append the values to the square grids and then you can simply use field calculator to determine percent mangrove coverage (100 * sum/count).

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark it as an answer if you'd like.